identify this Finnish movie about father who meets his son after years
It's about a Finnish drama movie. A father decides to find his son whom hasn't see for years. He goes out of his son's apartment and wait for him. The son comes back from a concert, he is a famous pianist. The father asks for a trip and says something about patrimony. He says that he will rent a car to his son but he steals one. They start to travel and then the father reveals that there is also a daughter, a blonde woman. They visit her, and for some reason the son gets high and hits the husband of the sister. Don't know what happens after that.

Year/decade you believe the movie was released in?

as it turns, 2012 :P thankss

Sounds like Road North (Tie pohjoiseen) from 2012. From an online review:

prodigal father Leo (Vesa-Matti Loiri) reappears drunk on the steps of the apartment of his son Timo (Samuli Edelmann), after abandoning him 35 years earlier. Where classical pianist Timo is disciplined, cultured, and tightly wound, overweight Leo is unprincipled, indulgent, and shamelessly spontaneous.
[...] the pair hit the road together as Leo wants the understandably resistant Timo to accompany him to the north to collect an inheritance. What keeps things interesting though are the layers of familial secrecy that are progressively unpeeled along the journey. Timo meets several relatives he never knew and learns about his father's checkered past (and, consequently, his own origins). Along the way, there's also a stowaway cat, a pot-smoking closet case, several misshaps, and even a musical number.

Here's the trailer:




yes, that's it, thank you!! :)
